# What does " A " next to file name in VS Code mean?

Tags: git, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

After typing to my code's terminal `git add recoverd_home_pg.dart` I see the mark `A` right after the file name on the VS Code, What does that `A` mean?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means it is a new file added (A) to your GIT project (or other source control system) but not committed yet. The (M) for the other file means modified so we know this file already are part of the GIT project but have been modified with changes yet to be committed.

Answer (score 12):

**A** -> Added
**M** -> Modified
**D** -> Deleted
**U** -> Untracked
**C** -> Conflict
**R** -> Renamed

Answer (score 3):

A is for added to git repo (a new file that has been added to the repository)